# How can I convert a cepstrum to temporal features, like interclick interval?

Tags: signal-detection

Signals like burst pulses often appear like tonal signals in a spectrogram.  [McCullough et al 2021](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/10.0005512) used cepstra to identify burst pulses, by capturing burst pulse harmonics in the spectrogram. How do you convert cepstral features (based on a spectrogram) to temporal burst pulse characteristics, like interclick interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cepstrum presents the temporal pulse characteristics and is inter alia used to estimate the interclick interval (IIRC in PAMGuard it is also used to estimate the IPI of sperm whales)

To see that take one definition of (complex) Cepstrum :

Cepstrum = ifft(log(fft(timeseries)))

- first fft transforms from time to frequency
- second fft transforms from frequency to time

other definitions of cepstrum can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum)